# Upload photo to server directory Ionic - Cordova plugin

Tags: php, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to upload the photo I've taken to database. The insert was success, all the details uploaded to database, and also the name of the picture. But somehow in my images folder the image cannot be open. It said "It looks like we don't support this file format". What's wrong?

Here is my php code

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","matawarga");
    if($conn->connect_error) {
        echo "Unable to connect, please try again";
        //die();
    }

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if(isset($postdata))
    {
        //$namesearch = $_POST['filter'];
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $userlogged = $request->usernamelogged;
        $judul = $request->judul;
        $tgl = $request->tglKejadian;
        $desc = $request->deskripsi;
        $instansi = $request->tujuan;
        $longitude = 0;
        $latitude = 0;

        $dateformat = strtotime($tgl);
        $newdateformat = date('Y-m-d', $dateformat);
        $myArr = array();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO kejadian(username,judul,deskripsi,instansi_tujuan,tanggal,longitude,latitude) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssii",$userlogged, $judul, $desc, $instansi, $newdateformat,$longitude,$latitude);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $idk = $stmt->insert_id;
            $image = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','', $url);
            $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
            $data = base64_decode($image);
            file_put_contents('images/'.$idk.'.jpg', $data);
            $url = ".jpg";

            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO gambar_kejadian(idkejadian,extension) VALUES (?,?)";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql3);
            $stmt->bind_param("is", $idk, $url);
            $stmt->execute();

$myArr['pesan'] = "Berhasil ditambahkan.";
        }
        else
        {
            $myArr['pesan'] = "Gagal" .$judul;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $myArr['pesan'] = "Gagal" .$desc;
    }

    echo json_encode($myArr);
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);` this part raises some concern for me, you shouldn't have to modify it beyond removing `data:image/jpeg;base64`

Comment: what is `$url`? it doesn't exist in the code you've provided, and `$desc` will never exist in that `} else {` at the bottom

Comment: don't recycle variables like that, `$url = '.jpg'` should be `$extension` or you'll end up confusing even yourself

Comment: also `$data = explode( ',', $base64_string )[1]` is probably the best way to deal with base64 encoded images, it'll return the part that matters (do your own sanity checking)

Comment: maybe you uploadead something else then jpeg, parse the `data:image/jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this bas64 to convert jpg

```
    $image = explode(";base64,", $url);
    $data = base64_decode($image[1]);
    file_put_contents('images/' . $idk . '.jpg', $data);
    $url = 'images/' . $idk . '.jpg';
```

Comment: my code is true, but turns out I need to get the encode first, Thanks